# Can functions be in a struct?

Tags: c++

Can we describe functions in a struct? For example, is this code valid?

```
struct function {
  int func() { return 5; }
};
```

Comment: You *still* haven't bothered to read a C++ book have you ?

Comment: @Paul It's not worth the effort trying to talk to this guy.

Comment: Yes you can, but **only if** it returns a value **below 7** (which is the case here).

Comment: stop decreasing mark  everybody

Comment: @ Neil Butterworth what to you want?

Comment: stooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooop   downvote

Comment: @davit: you'll find it very difficult to learn to write C++ well without first reading a good book to teach you the basics, and writing code to practise what you learn from the book. StackOverflow is a good place to ask if you have trouble understanding something, or if your code doesn't work, but some people will object to questions that simply ask how a basic language feature works; such a question isn't very helpful to you or anyone else. And some people will be rude when they object; that's human nature.

Comment: @davit: adding to what Mike Seymour said, you'll really have to be more mature with your comments.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a compiler. Compiler is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [only differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes) between a `struct` and `class` in C++ are:

> In C++, a structure is a class defined with the struct keyword. Its members and base classes are public by default. A class defined with the class keyword has private members and base classes by default. This is the only difference between structs and classes in C++.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There is no functional difference between a `class` and a `struct`, and anything you can do with one (such as defining a member function), you can do with the other.

If you're interested, the only difference is that members and base classes are `private` by default in a `class`, and `public` by default in a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, the difference to class is the access limitations to its members and methods. The struct has all its members and methods public by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is totally part of the standard.

A struct is a class with all its members public by default.