# implementation of queue

Tags: c++, queue

it is self learning process design queue here is code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Queue{

public:
     T * q;
     int n, head, tail;
public:
       Queue(int maxn){

           q=new T[maxn+1];
           n=maxn+1; head=n; 
           tail=0;



       }

       int  emty() const {
            return ((head%n)==tail);


       }
        void put(T k){
            a[tail++]=k; tail=tail%n;


        }
          T get(){
              head=head%n;  return q[head++];

          }
};
template <class T>
int main(){

    Queue<int>a(10);
    a.put(13);
    a.put(45);
    a.put(12);
    a.put(10);
    a.put(30);
    a.put(45);
    while(!a.emty()){
        cout<<a.get()<<"  ";


    }

    return 0;
}
```

here is mistakes

```
1>------ Build started: Project: QUEUE, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>D:\c++_algorithms\QUEUE\Debug\QUEUE.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

please help

Answer (score 3):

The `main` function mustn’t be a template. Simply remove the `template <class T>` before it to remove the compile error.

Comment: Defining `main` as a template really shows great incomprehension.  Hope OP is using a good C++ book.

Comment: @Steve - You may want to read back through his other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406407/can-functions-be-in-a-struct .  We're his C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

define main function like this: `int main()` . It is a special function that is run in the beginning and you cannot change it's signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
q=new T[maxn+1];
n=maxn+1; 
head=n; 
tail=0;
```

You create an Array of type T with size maxn+1

You may only use 0 up to maxn;

setting `head = maxn+1` may cause problems since this is the '\0' of the array

Also,

```
void put(T k)
{
    a[tail++]=k; 
    tail=tail%n;
}
```

What you do here is a bit weird. You assign the value k on a[tail] and then increase tail by 1, and then you assign tail the remainder of the division of k with maxn+1 which will always be the same as tail if im not mistaken ? Isnt this redundant ? Imagine tail is 2, and maxn is 15, 2 % 15 = 2. Generally, your whole approach is a bit weird.

Maybe you should do some Data Structures study. Look for Linked Lists. Using Arrays for such Structures is not wrong but is not correct either. What happens when the array is full ? How you going to keep track of all the new inserted elements on the array after that (assuming you make space) and how you gonna know which indeces are free to insert new stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, you should use the std queue.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/

Comment: OP noted in the question that this is an exercise for self-learning

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template < class type > class que {
    private:
        type arr[10000];
        int front, rear;
        public:
        que() {
            front = 0;
            rear = 0;
        }
        void insertion(type data) ;
        type deletion();
};

template<class type> type que<type>:: deletion() {
    cout<<front<<endl;
    return arr[front++];
}
template<class type> void que<type>:: insertion(type data) {
    cout<<rear<<" r"<<endl;
     arr[rear++] = data;
}

int main() {
    que<int> q;
    q.insertion(12);
    q.insertion(23);
    q.insertion(22222);
    cout<<q.deletion()<<endl;
    cout<<q.deletion()<<endl;
    cout<<q.deletion()<<endl;
}
```